# python Diffie-Hellman standard library

Tags: python, cryptography, diffie-hellman

Is there a standard library for python that implements Diffie-Hellman?
I've taken a look at openssl wrapper in python pyopenssl and it doesn't cover it.
I could not find it in NaCl or cryptography.io library either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been looking for this as well. As far as I know, No, there are no standard libraries at this time.

Though you can refer to this post for a [simple implementation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836320/on-diffie-hellman-key-exchange)

Or this github page for a more developed [poc](https://github.com/lowazo/pyDHE)

Edit: There appears to be a library for Diffie-Hellman [now.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/diffiehellman)

Comment: amazing, finally. I actually wrote my own wrapper around openssl to get around the problem. It was not that hard, I just wrote a server on a system socket pair that backed the openssl BIO.

Answer (score 0):

another library, seems more up-to-date https://pypi.org/project/pyDH/ with latest commit in 2019